# Django and Celery: unable to pickle task

Tags: python, django, celery, pickle, django-celery

thanks in advance :)

I have this async Celery task call:

```
update_solr.delay(id, context)
```

where id is an integer and context is a Python dict.

My task definition looks like:

```
@task
def update_solr(id, context):
    clip = Clip.objects.get(pk=id)
    clip_serializer = SOLRClipSerializer(clip, context=context)
    response = requests.post(url, data=clip_serializer.data)
```

where `clip_serializer.data` is a dict and `url` is a string representing a url.

When I try to call `update_solr.delay()`, I get this error:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed
```

Neither of the args to the task are instance methods so I'm confused.

When the task code is run synchronously, no error.

**Update: Fixed per comments about passing pk instead of object.**

Comment: To avoid race conditions and reduce payload size it's better to pass the model PK rather than a model instance.

Comment: Totally right, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Something *within the objects is* an instance method (that is, you put Object.foomethod in a dictionary, or something similar), in a place where pickle cannot pickle it.

Comment: Is that the full definition for the task as `url` may not be defined? Exceptions can't be pickled so try running the method without using Celery.

Comment: @AndrewS, it is not the full definition and it is defined in the code.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, thanks. I changed to passing an integer id and still get the same error...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `context` dict had an object in it, unbeknownst to me...

To fix, I executed code dependent on the `context` before the async call and just passed a dict with only native types:

```
def post_save(self, obj, created=False):
    context = self.get_serializer_context()
    clip_serializer = SolrClipSerializer(obj, context=context)
    update_solr.delay(clip_serializer.data)
```

The task ended up like this:

```
@task
def update_solr(data):
    response = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

This works out perfectly fine because the only purpose of making this an async task is to make the POST non-blocking.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the model instance primary key (`pk`). This is much simpler to pickle, reduces the payload and avoids race conditions.

Comment: Sorry - thought you said it was fixed ;-) Did you run the method without Celery?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pickle
class X:
    def y(self):
        pass

pickle.dumps(X.y)
```

Pickle works recursively so it might be anywhere in your object graph. You were given the solution - transfer the minimal objects only, that is primary keys and such, instead of Django model objects.